# "The Ministry Of Truth" challenge at CodeEval.com

Tags: programming-challenge, objective-c

I am working on another challenge from CodeEval.com and this is a bit harder.  I would like to get some feedback on my logic of solving the challenge.  Also there is probably one edge case that I missed because when I submit it to CodeEval I get different results.  Once I received 95% correct and another time 100%.

[The Ministry of Truth](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/143/)

> It's 1984, and you are working as an official at the Ministry of
>   Truth. You have intersected a message subjected to Big Brother's
>   doctrine.
>
> Your task is to delete letters from certain "utterances" in order to
>   replace them with an "utterance" approved by the Ministry.
>
> A "word" is a single sequence of Latin letters, and an "utterance" is
>   a sequence of multiple words and spaces.
>
> To compare two "utterances," you have to replace all blocks of spaces
>   with one space. Utterances are considered to be identical when
>   resulting expressions match.
>
> One line contains two different expressions separated by semicolon
>   ';'. The first expression is the original utterance, and the second
>   one is the utterance you want to get.
>
> If you cannot fulfill the order, print a single line «I cannot fix
>   history». Otherwise, output the original utterance by replacing the
>   letters that must be erased with underscore and by replacing all
>   blocks of white spaces with a single white space.
>
> Input Sample:
>
> ```
> Higher meaning;Hi mean
> this is impossible;im possible
> twenty   two minutes;two minutes
> Higher meaning;e
> ```
>
> Output Sample:
>
> Print the results, or "I cannot fix history" in case there is no
>   match. E.g.:
>
> ```
> Hi____ mean___ 
> I cannot fix history
>  ______ two minutes
>  ____e_ _______
> ```

Here is my solution:

```objc
-(void)ministryOfTruth
{
    NSString *line = @"ifcf hesaddasd  asdajds dsd f;";
    NSArray *lineArray = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]; //separate the original from approved
    NSArray *originalUtteranceWithSpaces= [[lineArray objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //separate the words from spaces
    NSMutableArray *originalUtterance  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString *word in originalUtteranceWithSpaces){
        //get rid of the spaces
        if (![word isEqual:@""]) {
            [originalUtterance addObject:word];
        }
    }


    NSArray *approvedUtterance = [[lineArray objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; //separate the approved
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSUInteger pos = 0;
    BOOL isWordFound = NO;
    if ([[approvedUtterance objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@""]) {
        isWordFound = NO;
    }else{
        for(NSString *approvedWord in approvedUtterance){
            //itterate through the approved utterances
            isWordFound = NO;
            while (pos < [originalUtterance count]) {
                //itterate through the words until you find the word that contains the approved word or goes through all the words
                NSString *originalWord = [originalUtterance objectAtIndex:pos];

                NSRange approvedWordLocation = [originalWord rangeOfString:approvedWord]; //check if the word contains approved word
                if (approvedWordLocation.location !=NSNotFound) {
                    isWordFound = YES;
                    int letterPos = 0;
                    NSMutableString *tempOriginalWord = [originalWord mutableCopy];
                    //if approved word found then create a mutable copy of it and replace all chars in originalWord that are not the word with _
                    while (letterPos < [originalWord length]) {
                        if ((letterPos < approvedWordLocation.location) || (letterPos >= approvedWordLocation.location + approvedWordLocation.length)) {
                            //check if letterPos is before the found word or after
                            [tempOriginalWord replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(letterPos, 1) withString:@"_"];
                        }
                        letterPos+=1;
                    }
                    //add to result array
                    [resultArray addObject:tempOriginalWord];
                    pos+=1; // move to the next original word
                    break; //get out of the while loop and check the next approved word
                }else{
                    isWordFound = NO;
                    //approvedWord not found set the whole word to _ and add it to the result array
                    NSMutableString *tempOriginalWord = [originalWord mutableCopy];
                    for (int letterPos = 0; letterPos < [originalWord length]; letterPos++) {
                        [tempOriginalWord replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(letterPos, 1) withString:@"_"];
                    }
                    [resultArray addObject:tempOriginalWord];
                    pos+=1; //move to the next original word
                }


            }
            if (!isWordFound) {
                //if approved word is not found then break out of the for loop and we are done.  I cannot fix history
                break;
            }

        }
        if (pos<[originalUtterance count] && isWordFound) {
            //if all approved words are found and we still have word from origingal utterance then replace all charcters with _
            NSMutableString *tempString = nil;
            for (NSUInteger i = pos; i<[originalUtterance count]; i++) {
                tempString = [[originalUtterance objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
                NSUInteger tempStringLength = [tempString length];
                for (NSUInteger i = 0; i<tempStringLength; i++) {
                    [tempString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(i,1) withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_"]];
                }
                [resultArray addObject:tempString];
            }
    }



    }
    if (isWordFound) {
        //Print results if all  approved words found
        NSString *resultString = [resultArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; //create NSString from array and put space between the words
        NSLog(@"resultArray %@",resultString);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"I cannot fix history");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is nice, but could use a few improvements:

---

> ```
> [array objectAtIndex:pos]
> ```

From [what I can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217352/acess-element-of-nsarray-with-its-index), `array[pos]` is valid syntax for Objective-C, and is much better.

---

You're missing, in more than a few places, whitespace. For example:

- `}else{` should be `} else {`,
- `@"resultArray %@",resultString` should have whitespace after the comma
- `NSMakeRange(i,1)` same as above: `NSMakeRange(i, 1)`
- `i<tempStringLength`: needs whitespace between the operator: `i < tempStringLength`
- `pos+=1`: same as above: `pos += 1` (*which could be* `pos++`*, right?*)

---

You have two main `for` loops in your code, and in one, you use the data type `int` and in the other `NSUInteger`.
I would suggest keeping them the same, and also their names the same as one is `letterPos` and the other `i`.

> ```
> for (int letterPos = 0
> for (NSUInteger i = 0
> ```

---

You have quite a few empty lines that could be removed, also.

---

Other than that, your code looks nice.